# How do I get the DNS server cmdlets to work on PowerShell in Windows 10?

Tags: powershell

When I try to use a DNS cmdlet, I get a "not recognized" error...

```
PS C:\Users\josh\Documents\GitHub\GoDaddy> get-dnsserverresourcerecord
get-dnsserverresourcerecord : The term 'get-dnsserverresourcerecord' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-dnsserverresourcerecord
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get-dnsserverresourcerecord:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How do I import these functions into Windows 10?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a non-server OS like Windows 10, you can add a bunch of Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) as an optional feature.

Starting with Windows 10 October 2018 Update, RSAT is included as a set of "Features on Demand" right from Windows 10. Go to "Manage optional features" in Settings and click "Add a feature" to see the list of available RSAT tools. Select and install the **RSAT: DNS Server Tools** feature.

Only if you're on an older version of Windows: see the instructions here and install the package https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

The `*-dnsserver*` cmdlets will immediately start working in PowerShell after that package is installed on the local machine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use implicit remoting as well, to temporarily import remote commands without installing RSAT:

```
$session = new-pssession -ComputerName server
Invoke-Command -command {Import-Module dnsserver} -Session $session
Import-PSSession -Session $session -Module dnsserver -Prefix RemoteDNS
```

The prefix will tag the imported commands so  you can keep track of the remote commands. Once you import the commands, you run them by using the prefix prior to the noun.

For example:

`Get-RemoteDNSdnsserverresourcerecord` instead of `get-dnsserverresourcerecord`

The prefix is optional, however.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this time of writing (Windows 10 Pro - 20H2) you can find RSAT(Remote Server Admin Tools) by using Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise in : 
Settings -> Apps -> Apps & features -> Optional features -> Add feature
Type in search field "RSAT" to choose modules you need

Answer (score 1):

2022 List Installed Windows Features on Win10 (Powershell)

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where Name -Match "RSAT.*" | Format-Table -Autosize
```

Install RSAT.DNS.TOOLS

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.Dns.Tools
```